# Cannot create package.json no matter what I try

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, npm

I have a react project and I'm having problems with trying to create `package.json` file on the branch i'm on. I have tried many of the top stack overflow answers in creating `package.json` but nothing seems to work. This project was working fine last night and `package.json` was there.

When I run `npm install` I get the following errors.

```
 npm install
 npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
 '/Users/wmannix/dev_repos/optic_link/integrator-ui/package.json'
 npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
 '/Users/wmannix/dev_repos/optic_link/integrator-ui/package.json'
 npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0- 
 dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 
 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
 npm WARN integrator-ui No description
 npm WARN integrator-ui No repository field.
 npm WARN integrator-ui No README data
 npm WARN integrator-ui No license field.
```

I even tried running `npm init -y` to create a new `package.json` and I tried adding the configuration my self by pasting in the config from a `package.json` I have in a react project on another branch but I ran into a number of problems with that as well including having to remove or stash `package.json` and `package-lock.json` every time I want to switch branch or pull the latest from the branch which never happened before.

```
git pull
Updating 73f82bc34..185bce04c
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
integrator-ui/package-lock.json
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting
```

Any idea as to what is happening?

This is my file directory

[File directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdvGv.png)

When I do a git status, you can see my `package-lock.json` file is in my Untracked files. I pushed this react project up to Github and I thought it might be that the `README` file and `package.json` files might have been added to `gitignore` but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

If your local project is a copy of remote. Try this:

1. Delete local project
2. `git clone <your repo name>`
3. enter to cloned folder and `npm init`